# Ошибка при активации cmake на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

вот сама ошибка:

**CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.**

**Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR**

**used as include directory in directory /home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp**

**used as include directory in directory /home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp**

**used as include directory in directory /home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp**

**used as include directory in directory /home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp**

**used as include directory in directory /home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp**

**used as include directory in directory /home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp**

**used as include directory in directory /home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp**

**-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!**

**See also "/home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".**

**See also "/home/roman/tgbot/tgbot-cpp/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".**

подскажите пожалуйста как решить

с этого сайта брал инфу как устанавливать https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp

Comment: Я думаю в вашем случае это не трогать СPP14 и взять например Python исполнение тгбота) Потому что у вас проблемы с чтением документации или хотя-бы Readme.md а без этих навыков CPP изучать невозможно от слова совсем.

Comment: @EugeneX я просто пытался его сделать по туториулу) и особо то и не читал...